# How to create a SQL Safe string in Python if I cannot use prepared statements?

Tags: python, sql, security

I have a situation where my app needs to send SQL Queries to another external application (which is controlled by a third party) via an API call.  I need to implement some SQLInjection protections on my end.  Every single guide and stackoverflow post I've read insists on using Prepared statements such as

```
import psycopg2

with psycopg2.connect(user='user', password='password', host='host', database='database') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    name = "John"
    query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ILIKE %s%"
    cursor.execute(query, (name,))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

The problem is we do not have a direct database connection, or psycopg.  What is my alternative here?  Should I just do something like
`sql_string.replace("'", "''")`

or is that also unsafe? I feel like a bad actor could get around that somehow. The only part of the query controlled by user input is the value of the column name thankfully, but I still feel like there's a vulnerability there.

Is there a way I could use a method like this without instantiating a connection?

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify

And before you ask, yes I am directly talking with this third party about why they do not have support for prepared statements, but I am also on a bit of a time crunch so I need to formulate an alternative.

Comment: so in short, from your app, you send a sql query to the 3rd party app, which process the query and fetch the data from the database, where you don't have access or contrrol. ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  I am using ILike in my queries but its very similar to the query example in the OP

Comment: So you control database ? 3rd party app or you need to handle case where database is only for reading, updating and not for deletion and have some checks on queries.

Comment: Is there anything to prevent you install Postgres and psycopg2 locally to generate the statements? You only need the connection, you don't need a copy of the actual database to use `mogrify`.

Comment: Correct escaping is the key. All strings must escape quotes correctly.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I was looking into this earlier. The app is not connected to a postgres db, but you're saying I can instantiate a connection without an actual database and use mogrify?

Comment: You need a running Postgres server to connect to, but you don't need the table definitions from the third party database.